# techniques to implement "dependency injection"

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

By "dependency injection" I mean the OO notion of a passing some sort of pointer to code. In FP, this would be done using higher order functions.

In xslt 2+ there seems to be these alternatives

- passing functions (as per functional programming)
- passing psuedo 'modes', whereby you pass an explicitly constructed element (or value embedded in some node structure) and match it.

(there are other alternatives that statically inject code using include/import where templates in the including stylesheet override or interact with the included stylesheet, but this is more akin to 'template methods' i.e. static composition)

Is there an idiomatic/pattern for this in the XSLT community?

(it would be nice to be able to "bundle" the injection somehow, like an interface or a typeclass does, this would seem to be possible using the psuedo modes technique by embedding the 'modes' as elements or values inside another element, or a 'mode' is a 'bundle', but not obviously so using functions directly)

---

I havent given explicit examples, let me know if you need them to make it clear what i mean.

---

actually there is a 3rd alternative where you return a DSL, and 'interpret it', and different contexts interpret in different ways, this is probably akin to the "pipeline" technique, and whilst I like it very much, its a bit overkill when you just want to inject a tiny nuance.

---

Examples:

(all use this xml - which is irrelevant

```
<root>
    <foo/>
</root>
```

)

#1 'higher order functions' (i think this may be stolen from a previous answer by Martin Honnen on HOFs)

the functions 'apply-function' allows a function to be 'injected' which it then executes, obviously any function with a compatible signature can be injected. This is the default FP technique.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
    xmlns:my="my"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <!-- Define a function that accepts a function parameter -->
    <xsl:function name="my:apply-function" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:param name="function" as="function(xs:integer) as xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$function($input)"/>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <!-- Define a sample function to be passed as a parameter -->
    <xsl:function name="my:double" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$value * 2"/>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <!-- Main template -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <!-- Call my:apply-function and pass my:double as a parameter -->
            <xsl:variable name="result" select="my:apply-function(5, my:double#1)"/>
            <doubled-value>
                <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
            </doubled-value>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#2 'psuedo modes'

this way you explicitly encode your 'choice' in some structure and then match on it.

i.e. the 'function pointer' is encoded as

```
<Mode value='double'/>
```

I suspect there is a better label for this technique but for me it feels like a machanism to emulate runtime 'modes'.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
    xmlns:my="my"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:template mode="inject" match="Mode[@value = 'double']">
        <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$value * 2"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="inject" match="Mode[@value = 'treble']">
        <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$value * 3"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Main template -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <doubled-value>
                <xsl:variable name="mode">
                    <Mode value='double'/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="inject" select="$mode">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="5"/>                    
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </doubled-value>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#3 DSL/interpreter

here the 'callee' code returns some domain specific language encoded as xml by my:makeDSL which is then interpreted by a client specific intepreter.

Here the depedency isnt really injected, its externalised, and then intepreted in the way that callee wants, but the result is the same.

("nop" instructions are just there for illustration)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
    xmlns:my="my"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:template mode="inject" match="Mode[@value = 'double']">
        <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$value * 2"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="inject" match="Mode[@value = 'treble']">
        <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$value * 3"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template mode="double" match="nop"/>
        
    <xsl:template mode="double" match="inject">
        <xsl:sequence select="2 * @value"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template mode="treble" match="nop"/>
    
    <xsl:template mode="treble" match="inject">
        <xsl:sequence select="3 * @value"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Main template -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <doubled-value>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="double" select="my:makeDSL(5)"/>
            </doubled-value>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:function name="my:makeDSL">
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <nop/>
        <inject value="{$value}"/>
        <nop/>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you use higher-order functions and e.g. declare/use a function parameter of a certain type (.e.g. `<xsl:param name="my-func" as="function(item(), node()?) as node()*"/>`, isn't that some kind of type constraints, like you have with dependency injection (where you inject a certain type/interface)?

Comment: you are injecting 1 function? in OO you inject N methods, and in an FP world, you can inject N functions embedded in some data structure (like type classes).

Comment: if you use the psuedo mode thing (u probably have a better term for it), then you CAN embed the psuedo mode names in some element structure, its all a bit untyped though

Comment: Let's see what others have to say, I have brought the question to the attention of the xml.com slack community, so perhaps some software engineers with a deeper understanding of DI and functional programming and XSLT do show up here.

Comment: I'm actually recently a member of xml.com, but i still come here. I've added a 3rd alternative used in FP, but it feels overkill, in an FP you mix and match these techniques quite a lot, in XSLT it forces you to think about it, and because templates exist globally, too many 'interpreters' clutter the code

Comment: I think for those of us more familiar with XSLT than general OO, a concrete example would help

Comment: I have played with XPath Function Libraries and they seem to provide a solution similar to what you need. An XPath Function Library is an XPath expression (residing in a text file or resource) that is dynamically evaluated (loaded) and that produces a map, whose keys are function names and their corresponding values - the definitions of the function with that name, In case you are interested to know more about this, please, indicate so in another comment here, then I would be glad to describe this in a reply to this question.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - I am interested as long as its not overly contrived. As I've said I CAN do what i want simply by passing some structure that is matched...effectively a runtime psuedo 'mode', but even that is contrived

Comment: @TomHillman - hello again!...the OO analogy is just a weak hand wavy sort of reference to a well known technique in that community - actually the FP notion of HOFs is better, but I'll add examples

Comment: examples of each technique added.

Comment: MrD at KookerellaLtd, Please provide an email address (send it to dnovatchev  at googles-mail-service) and I will give you access to https://github.com/dnovatchev/FunXPath  . Then I will be glad to answer any questions or suggestions that you might have.

Comment: ive emailed that address (i think)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - I believe ive emailed u

Comment: Mark, I replied. Look at your mail.

Comment: actually ive worked out how to embed a function in a map, so I can now basically do "dictionary passing" as a Haskell dev would...well in a very primitive manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment, the answer seems to be no (there is no idiomatic approach), at least not consciously.

The pipelining pattern is I suspect idiomatic but in a more general sense, and the language encourages a approach similar to OO template methods (i.e. static injection) where stylesheets are included/imported and templates are overriden via mode.

Thats not to say that it cannot be achieved.

The techniques in the question are all applicable, and a technique similar to 'dictionary passing' can be used by embedding functions in Maps.

Heres a simple example using a "monoid" i.e. things that can be added together.

We have 2 monoid "dictionaries" encoded as maps, one for integers and one for strings, and we pass (inject) each into some code that "adds" some values and returns the answer.

The input xml is this

```
<root>
    <foo value1="123" value2="456"/>
</root>
```

the stylesheet processes the foo element 1st as integers and then as strings

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:kooks="kookerella.com"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.1">
    
    <xsl:function name="kooks:stringAdd" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="s1" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="s2" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="concat($s1,$s2)"/>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:variable name="stringMonoid" as="map(*)">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'zero'" select="''" as="xs:integer"/>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'add'" select="kooks:stringAdd#2"/>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:function name="kooks:integerAdd" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:param name="i1" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:param name="i2" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$i1 + $i2"/>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:variable name="integerMonoid" as="map(*)">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'zero'" select="0" as="xs:integer"/>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'add'" select="kooks:integerAdd#2"/>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <integer>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="root/foo">
                    <xsl:with-param name="monoid" select="$integerMonoid"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </integer>
            <string>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="root/foo">
                    <xsl:with-param name="monoid" select="$stringMonoid"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </string>
        </root>    
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="foo">
        <xsl:param name="monoid"/>
        
        <result 
            value1="{@value1}" 
            value2="{@value2}" 
            zero="{map:get($monoid,'zero')}"
            sum="{map:get($monoid,'add')(@value1,@value2)}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which results in this

```
<root>
   <integer>
      <result value1="123" value2="456" zero="0" sum="579"/>
   </integer>
   <string>
      <result value1="123" value2="456" zero="" sum="123456"/>
   </string>
</root>
```

This is of course just a variation of passing functions as parameters in i.e. higher order functions, but the ability to embed the function inside a map, makes it possible to package them up in something like a "typeclass".

(note to OOers, these psuedo typeclasses are not objects, if you view them as objects, then they are objects with no state, their purpose is simply to package up functions not to encapsulate state)